# array of string to string

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

Can I use JSONPath expressions to get a string out of an array of string?

Example, here is an array of strings:

```
{
    "objects": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ]
}
```

and the expresion

```
$.objects[:]
```

will result into

```json
[
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
]
```

however I want to have something like

```json
[
    "a b c"
]
```

or better

```json
[
    "a, b, c"
]
```

is this possible?

Comment: What you want is an invalid json

Comment: Thank you @Serge for your precise and detailed answer. This really helped me a lot with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you don't any path, this is enough

```
var newArray = [oldArray.objects.join(",")];
```

or if for some reasons you still want jsonPath

```
var newArray = [jsonPath(oldArray,"$.objects").join(",")];
```

output

```
[
    "a, b, c"
]
```